# Updated eclipse (Juno SR2), but now can't update

Tags: eclipse

On:

```
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

However, now when I go to do an update I get: 'There are no update sites to search. Do you wish to open the "Available Software Sites" preferences?'

Doing so, shows that the list is empty, and there are no update sites anymore. ;(

Anyone else had this problem?
Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following xml code as xml file and import it going `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Avaliable Software Sites`.  Maybe there are a little bit more update sites (I exported them from my eclipse) as on the standard eclipse, but it would fix your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmarks>
    <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo" selected="true" name="Indigo repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/" selected="true" name="Juno"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/update" selected="false" name="Linux Tools"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/updates-nightly" selected="false" name="Linux Tools"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/repository/" selected="true" name="Orbit-I20110523182458"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120526062928/repository/" selected="true" name="Orbit-I20120526062928"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project Updates"/>
   <site url="http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/" selected="true" name="Update Site"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/edapt/update-site/" selected="true" name="Update Site"/>
   <site url="http://texlipse.sourceforge.net" selected="true" name="update site: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/" selected="true" name="Xtext All In One - Releases"/>
   <site url="http://download.itemis.de/updates/" selected="true" name="Xtext Composite Update Site"/>
   <site url="http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/dsdp/org.eclipse.tm.tcf/releases/0.4.0" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/3.7" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/jwt/update-site" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.1/update-site/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/eef/updates/0.7.1/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmf/updates/milestones/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmf/updates/releases/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/updates/releases/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/xpand/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/milestones/0.8" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.6" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/indigo/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/objectteams/updates/2.0" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/objectteams/updates/contrib" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/1.3/runtime" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/1.3/tooling" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/stp/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/actf/0.9/update-site/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/emft/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/updates/udc/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tm/updates/3.3" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/milestones/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20100519200754/repository" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120119162704/repository" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/updateSite" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ptp/updates/indigo/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/3.7" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.itemis.com/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/diffmerge/releases/0.1.0/EMF-DiffMerge-0.1.0.v20121106-1043-Site-Incubation.zip" selected="true" name=""/>
   <site url="http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/?project=search#search" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=papyrus#papyrus" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
</bookmarks>
```

Comment: potentially a solution, but it is weird that rolling fwd to the latest version would have this behavior as 'expected'. (I currently took the zipped-backup I made of eclipse before doing the update, and am just running that again.  If I do attempt to update again I'll export my own xml bookmark list, just in case.)

Comment: Was the update successful or you got some errors during the update?

Comment: if you can reproduce the problem, you can make a bug report to eclipse.

Comment: yep. it is on my todo list. ;)

Comment: oh. and I am going to accept this answer as 'good enough', as it answers the how to fix portion of my question. (though the why is still currently a mystery ;)). :)